# How do I set headers for an Rspec post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my Rspec controller test function I've tried all the following:

`post('pay', {p: 'x'}, password: 'x')`

`post('pay', {p: 'x'}, {password: 'x'})`,

`request.headers['password'] = 'x'; post('pay', {p: 'x'})`

None sends headers - in my controller I can't see any headers when saying `puts headers.inspect`. (But the param `p` is received correctly.)

**How do you set headers in Rspec?**

- I'm using rspec-rails 3.1.0, ruby 2.3.0, rails 4.2.7.
- My controller inherits from `ActionController::Base`.
- My spec has `require spec_helper` (and I tried without it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.headers['password'] = 'x'` is correct. In your controller, however, you should be inspecting `request.headers` and not just `headers`.